# Very large tree: What is wrong with our branch workflow and how to fix it?

Tags: git, merge, azure-devops, rebase, git-flow

My team has started working under git with a workflow close to GitFlow.
We had several constraints:

- We need a branch with all features currently in development to provide users with a testing environment. We called that branch *integration*
- We need a branch with only functional features that users validated and every technical feature that passed Pull-Request, to be able to create a package for release. We called that branch *dev*
- We want to develop our features into branches, those start with *evol-* and branch off of *dev*
- We want every feature branch to benefit from any technical (= no need to be user-validated) advance : we decided to cherry pick technical commits from *evol* branches into dev (into *tech-* branches off dev that get pull-requested into dev). We then merge dev into any *evol* branch that needs it

When a feature is ready for testing we merge it into *integration*, have user test it, and if valid merge the feature branch it into *dev*.

This means many merges to integration, from feature branching off of many different versions of *dev*, so we have this kind of tree (On the left is currently the *integration* branch)

[image: horrible git tree]

The team size is 5 devs. We usually have many feature branches existing at the same time, each taking a long time to be complete and validated.

**Because of the way Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) works with pull requests** (showing any diff from the source branch since it diverged from target, rather than a simulated merge true result) we would like to reduce the difference induced by feature branches that get the latest technical advance from *dev*.

I suppose the way to go is to `rebase` them onto *dev* rather than merge dev into them, but this shows a problem when it comes to the merges to integration: The merges keep pointing to old commits rather than the new commit from the rebase.

I got the result I wanted with `git rebase -p --onto new old` for every merge but that seems a bit wrong especially when there has been more than a couple of merges from the feature to integration.

[image: After two rebase --onto for B and B2]

I did :
`git rebase -p --onto <new B> <old B>`
`git rebase -p --onto <new B2> <old B2>`
I even got away with a better looking tree because git deleted the first merge after B.

Is there a way to either :

- Specify an option to rebase so that the merges using that rebased branch's commit as source get updated with the new ones
- Fix our workflow so that we no longer have an horrible megatree, and no problem to rebase (maybe delete in some way the merges to *integration* from a feature before rebasing it)

Answer (score 0):

It appears we can use `git merge --squash` to create a commit on *integration* that bears the diffs from the source branch but has no parent pointer to that branch. This would allow us to easily rebase *evol* branches on dev HEAD without having conflicting pointers to old commits in *integration* merges.
I will discuss this with my team and have a few days trial before updating this answer with more details.

See picture below :
[image: effects of squash merge and rebase]

I renamed *evol-B* to *evol-B-rebased* after doing `git rebase dev` in order to keep this view and still be able to create a pull request on github.
The commits on *integration* are squash merges created with `git merge --squash --ff evol-[A|B]`

This seems a lot better than what our original tree looked like. We just ought to make sure only squash merges are allowed to *integration*, and that everyone puts the name of the source branch in that squash's commit message.

The only thing not perfect yet is that the pull request would still show all the feature's commits rather than just those who are not yet squashed on *integration*, but that's a necessary evil I guess.

Here is what it looks like after merging *evol-B-rebased* back into *dev* and cleaning up the old *evol-B* :
[image: clean tree]
Branches even fall in their own swimming lanes on their own, which is nice !

**As for long feature branches** which would generate a huge pull request when merging to *integration*, we just can create a sub-branch for each part of that feature and pull request *those* back into the feature's main branch (just like sprint branches / sprint integration branches)